# Hilt - Java How to runtime inject String from Fragment to ViewModel constructor?

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

I have a String inside my Fragment that I'm trying to inject into the Fragment's ViewModel.

I've been following this tutorial
https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2287

but I can't get the correct syntax from kotlin to java to work.

```
@AssistedFactory
public interface MainViewModelFactory {
    MainViewModel create(String s);
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "MainViewModel";

    @Inject
    public MainViewModel(@Assisted String testString) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MainViewModel: Success injecting: " + testString);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static ViewModelProvider.Factory provideFactory(
            MainViewModelFactory assistedFactory,
            String s
    ){
        return new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
                return (T) assistedFactory.create(s);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
    @Inject
    MainViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;

    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.provideFactory(viewModelFactory, "Test string"));

        //This line fails to even compile because I can't figure out how to fix my syntax from the kotlin to java conversion.
        
    }
```

[image]

How can I correctly provide the `ViewModel` from my factory method?

When I try to compile it I get

`An assisted factory's abstract method must return a type with an @AssistedInject-annotated constructor.` on my factory class's method `create`.

Edit:

I know you can use a module to provide the string, but I'm using it as a simple example before I try to get it working with injecting an object.

Using Hilt 2.37:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.37'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.37'
```

Comment: Is your String an argument (i.e., in your Activity's `getIntent().getExtra()` or your Fragment's `getArguments()`) or some other random String?

Comment: I was using a string as a simple implementation. But I was trying to pass an object from a parent fragment to its child fragment and then to the child fragment's viewmodel. I didn't pass move it across the fragments with intents, just using the constructor of the child fragment. ```ChildDialogFragment(Plant plant)``` and then injected that into the ChildFragment's viewmodel. what are your thoughts on this? Is that bad practice

Comment: `ChildDialogFragment(Plant)` won't work after a configuration change or process death and recreation anyways (as FragmentManager won't know how to reconstruct your fragment without a custom FragmentFactory or a no argument constructor), so you really should be using arguments anyways.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks for the tip. BTW, is this the correct way to do it, or is there another solution to this problem? If there is, could you please post it so I could use my bounty?

Answer (score 3):

Took two days to figure it out...but here's how to runtime inject (assisted injection) with hilt using Java.

Requirements: `Dagger 2.31+`

Important notes:

**DO NOT annotate** your ViewModel with `@HiltViewModel` or it will throw a compile time exception which did not help me identify the issue at all.

```
 ViewModel constructor should be annotated with @Inject instead of @AssistedInject.
  [Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.
```

Full code with `String` example:

```
@AssistedFactory
public interface MainViewModelFactory {
    MainViewModel create(String s);
}
```

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "MainViewModel";

    @AssistedInject
    public MainViewModel(@Assisted String testString) {
        Log.d(TAG, "MainViewModel: Success injecting: " + testString);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static ViewModelProvider.Factory provideFactory(
            MainViewModelFactory assistedFactory,
            String s
    ){
        return new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
                return (T) assistedFactory.create(s);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    MainViewModelFactory viewModelFactory;

    private MainViewModel mainViewModel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mainViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(
                this, 
                MainViewModel.provideFactory(viewModelFactory, "Test string") 
        ).get(MainViewModel.class);

}
```

Took me a while to figure out there was a second param for `ViewModelProvider` which needed the injected `ViewModelFactory` to create the `ViewModelProvider`

Hopefully this answer helps people in the future. I couldn't find any examples of how to do it.

Helpful answers:

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2287#issuecomment-761811164

Converting the kotlin way of creating the Java equivalent of `ViewModelProviders` was quite confusing...

Answer (score 0):

First, You must add @Inject Annotation On Constructor Of Your Class
Second, if your Constructor of your class has an argument or Object that is hard to Instantiate for dagger, You have to provide it from Module Class.
for Example if your class use String Class or use an interface, abstract class that cannot be instantiate, you must provide an instance of that class in your Module Class.
In your ViewModel Class you can get it like repository class, because repository class is a simple class, dagger knows how to instantiate it, so there is no problem.

```
public class FragmentViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final RemoteRepository remoteRepository;
    private final TestClass testClass;

    @Inject
    public CardInfoViewModel(RemoteRepository remoteRepository, TestClass testClass) { //How to inject object from Fragment into constructor?
        this.remoteRepository = remoteRepository;
        this.testClass = testClass;
    }
}
```

module class

```
@InstallIn(Singletone.class)
@Module
public class ModuleClass {

    @Singletone
    @Provide
    public TestClass provideTestClass() {
        return new TestClass("Some Text");
    }
}
```

Comment: The ```TestClass``` is just a simple example. I need to inject it into the ```ViewModel``` at runtime because the ```TestClass``` is created after fetching the object from an API call

Comment: Dagger is fully static and compile time, it's impossible

Comment: Hilt can use assisted injection but I am unsure of the syntax.

Comment: it is not possible, dagger is a compile time library, not working in your case, You cannot inject a class in runtime, maybe in the feature you can, I'm not sure, but at this time, it is not POSIBLE :)

Comment: A tricky way you can use, but I don't know exactly what you want to do is you know about an object you are getting from an API, so create it your self, and you can fill it from API and inject it to your viewModel, as far as I know it not a good way to pass an data to view model, if you use a pattern in your application like MVVM it's a one directional pattern.

Comment: ```it is not possible``` it's actually possible https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2287#issuecomment-761811164

Comment: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html#:~:text=Dagger,assisted%E2%80%9D)%20by%20the%20user.

Comment: How to inject a class into compiled code?